# Adding special character in keyframe names with LESS

Tags: css, less

I'm trying to generate keyframes with less. Here is my code with the result and expected output.
I searched on how to add special characters in variables in less but couldn't find a solution for this problem.

Can anyone tell how the 0'%' can be convert to 0% (same for other percentage values)

```
@keyframes spin{
@sign:'%';
.rotate(0,0,90,25);
.rotate(@percent:0, @deg:0,@degDiff, @percentDiff) when (@percent <= 100) {
  @{percent}@{sign}   {
        transform: rotate(@deg deg);
    }
    .rotate(@percent+@percentDiff, @deg+@degDiff, @degDiff, @percentDiff);
}
}
```

output

```
@keyframes spin {
  0'%' {
    transform: rotate(0 deg);
  }
  25'%' {
    transform: rotate(90 deg);
  }
  50'%' {
    transform: rotate(180 deg);
  }
  75'%' {
    transform: rotate(270 deg);
  }
  100'%' {
    transform: rotate(360 deg);
  }
}
```

expected result

```
@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0 deg);
  }
  25% {
    transform: rotate(90 deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(180 deg);
  }
  75% {
    transform: rotate(270 deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360 deg);
  }
}
```

Comment: Multiply by `1deg` instead of trying to append `deg`. I remember seeing similar questions in the past. (*Edit:* Oops, sorry I thought you asked about the space before `deg` and not the `%`.)

Comment: @Harry thanks, it worked

Comment: You're welcome @HimanshuTanwar. I'll proceed to close it as a dupe.